# ORA-00439: feature not enabled: Application Role

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, oracle11g

I use Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 on Ubuntu 16.04. When I want to create a new role by 'USING' expression, the Oracle throws the following error:

> ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-00439: feature not enabled: Application Role

And the result of `select * from v$option where parameter = 'Application Role';` is False. I was wondering if it is possible to enable this feature or not? And how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the sql statement you are executing.

Comment: @OldProgrammer, the problem was solved. I should have used enterprise edition.